# What happens when I divide by zero?

Tags: math, computer-science, divide-by-zero

Now I'm not asking about the mathematical answer of dividing by zero, I want to what my computer does when it tries to divide by zero?

I can see different answers depending on what level we look at?
Looking at a high-level I expect the language specification may just say "hey you can't do that throw an error"

Looking at an assembly level, will the CPU try to call the divide instruction when we try to divide by 0?

If it does that'll take us to the machine code level. What happens now?

Now if that doesn't happen and we force it to happen, what would the result be?

Comment: architecure dependent - see [here for intel](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf)

Comment: one assumes the [raptors](http://xkcd.com/292/) get him? - and OP intel throws a 'Divide Error' exception - although machine level exceptions are different to try catch exceptions

Comment: Seriously now. If you had a computer, you'd be able to test what happens. And according to your definition, C is not a high level language...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming problem but is rather a question about CPU architecture. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at an assembly level, will the CPU try to call the divide instruction when we try to divide by 0?

Yep instruction gets fetched and decoded. What happens then? The divisor is found to be zero and the process stops doing what it's doing. It throws some kind of an exception, pipeline (if there is one) is flushed and most likely control jumps to some predefined error handling code - often the OS controls a machine level jump table called an interrupt vector (or this could be a separate to the interrupt vector table).

There are many architectures however, and things like error handling vary. Intel x86 follows above procedure at least.

> If it does that'll take us to the machine code level. What happens now?

I have no idea what that means. From the CPU's perspective, it is all machine code level.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're asking is what's going to happen if we perform binary division algorithm with 0 in the denominator.

The algorithm will go into an infinite loop, and the quotient will grow larger and larger until it exhausts all available memory.

Comment: If this is meant seriously then it's seriously broken.  If it's meant humorously, well, it's not very humorous as written.

Comment: It's meant seriously. Would you mind enlightening me?

Comment: Read the other answer. To which I'd add that division algorithms generally test the divisor at the beginning and raise some sort of error if it is found to be 0.

Comment: Well, I think you didn't understand my answer. CPU is obviously not going to try to divide by 0, it will throw an exception or set a flag. But it's still interesting to think what's going to happen if we try to carry out an *algorithm* such as long division or division by repeated subtraction. Which is what my answer is about.

Comment: You're quite right, I do not understand your answer.  Any algorithm which proposes to implement division by repeated subtraction which does not check that the divisor is non-zero is a broken algorithm for exactly the reason you explain: if it fails to make that check it will only terminate when a counter overflows.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think what is meant by "perform... algorithm with 0 in the denominator" here is "ignore any preconditions and execute the algorithm anyway". So while the full algorithm will check for a 0 denominator and produce an error, OP's question seems to be asking what would happen if this check was not performed. (This is what this answer is addressing)

Comment: @SamYonnou: yeah, and I think that's what OP meant by asking "Now if that [division by 0] doesn't happen and we force it to happen, what would the result be?"