# On the machine level an appliccation runs as in binary, then when a run time error occurs, how does it render back to error codes?

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am running the below program :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    while(1)
    {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        cout << 9/a << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the step by step process is

1. the above code gets compiled and successively converted into binary fotmat.
2. the binary code instructions get executed step by step.

so when I provide the input with : 0, I receive following on the console : Floating point exception: 8

Now my question is how does this "Floating point exception: 8" gets printed on console when machine is executing binary instructions.

Comment: @Ron , plz explain where my assumption is wrong

Comment: "With yet even more binary codes", of course. Are you not sure about what happens inside when a program is "run"?

Comment: It depends how you run it. An IDE will find exceptions and report them. From a prompt these are baked into the exe. When you invoke `\` there's a lot going on in there.

Comment: @doctorlove , I am running it with g++ file.cpp

Comment: @Ron , I do not think there is any relation between "binary nature of machines has anything to do with how runtime libraries format and display messages on standard output", my question is when an exception is occured on the machine level, what follows after that till I see "Floating point exception: 8" on the console

Comment: This mishap is detected by the processor, it generates a trap that is handled by the OS.  Specific to Unix, it raises the SIGFPE signal and if the program doesn't handle it then the CRT does by terminating the program after displaying this message.  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html

Comment: A huge load of this  stuff is OS/driver/video/etc specifc. It would take a book to explain 'exactly'.  Far too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic and logic unit (ALU) of the CPU will contain a register of error flags. Divide by zero is one of those. The ALU will likely spot the zero in the denominator or choke and set the flag.

Either way, at the machine level an interrupt will occur, which is what we (eventually) see as an exception. It traps (via an interrupt vector) to a section of binary code for exception handling, which is where higher level exception handling is invoked from.

More detail's tend to be architecture dependent but could cause the pipeline to be invalidated.

Comment: at the machine level after the interrupt is occured, what exactly happens after that, till I see "Floating point exception: 8" on my console

Comment: I've explained from the machine level to the C/C++ interrupt handler. Explaining C++ at the machine level is the task of the debugger / compiler. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842515/what-happens-when-i-divide-by-zero if I was not clear